# Wrap a GWT widget in a web component

Tags: gwt, web-component, gwt-jsinterop

I am trying to use gwt with web component, I'd like to reuse some widgets by wrapping them (and use them in a microfrontend scenario but one step a time). I am using `jsinterop` in a dummy project but I can't use my widget in the javascript part. I use @JsType to share some classes (widgets and what they must render), here is a snippet of my simple web component:

```
import './gwtjs/gwtjs.nocache.js';
window.customElements.define('effort-component', class EffortComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ 'mode': 'open' });
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('connected!');

    var actv1 = new edu.pezzati.gwtjs.client.provided.model.Activity;
    ...
    var model = [];
    model[0] = [actv1, actv2];
    model[1] = [eff1, eff2, eff3];

    var effortTable = edu.pezzati.gwtjs.client.provided.EffortTable();
    this._shadowRoot.appendChild(effortTable);
    effortTable.refresh(model);
  }
});
```

when component is connected I get:

```
gwtjs.component.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: edu is not defined
at HTMLElement.connectedCallback (gwtjs.component.js:11)
at gwtjs.component.js:2
```

I am using `gwt 2.8.1`, mojo's `gwt-maven-plugin 2.8.1` with the `<generateJsInteropExports>true</generateJsInteropExports>` flag to use JsInterop. You can find the project [here](https://github.com/fpezzati/gwtjs).

Comment: GWT compiler does not produce JS modules, so import may not work. Try to load nocache.js somewhere in your page before using web component. And note, that nocache, depending on linker, is just loader for a permutation js. So using of the web component should be deferred until the permutation js is loaded.

Comment: @AlexanderLeshkin thankyou for your reply. Maybe I have to move from a javascript webcomponent to an html webcomponent where to load the .nocache.js synchronously and then import the whole stuff by html import. Am I getting it right?

Comment: @AlexanderLeshkin I'd like to keep my web component a javascript one (a .js file). How to load the .nocache.js file in my webcomponent? I tried the 'ajax' way and the 'script tag' way (I added a branch to my repository) but no success.. Thankyou.

Comment: You can try to use SSO-linker and <collapse-all-properties /> in GWT module descriptor. In this case code should be compiled directly into one permutation in nocache.js. But looking at the code, I'm thinking that more effort should be done to make it working. You will not be able to append EffortTable instance to shadow root, since it is not a DOM element - it is a simple JS object that wraps GWT widget.